# Using Fabric.js, can I export the image from my canvas as a vector file and then be import it back?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm creating a simple graphic editor with JavaScript/Fabric.js and now I want to be able to save my canvas image as a vector file ( like you can do with adobe illustrator ) and then be able to import it back. Is that possible?

Comment: have you tried something？

Comment: I usually learn stuff by seeing how they're done first and then adding my own twist, however, since I don't know what I'm looking for, my google searches bore no fruit + I'm not even sure if that's possible so that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: **toSVG:** [canvas.toSVG](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#toSVG)

**fromSVG:** `fabric.loadSVGFromURL` and `fabric.loadSVGFromString`